How to secure Logout Request to Auth0 Secure
We are using auth0-react library for auth0 integration, and using
{ logout } = useAuth0(); method for logout purpose
If this request is intercepted, it could potentially log out all logged-in users. How can we implement CSRF token protection for this Auth0 request?
